# How to retrieve multiple device attributes from a single HTTP request in Thingsboard?

Tags: httprequest, thingsboard

I want to retrive multiple device attributes from a single HTTP API call. TB allows me to perform get request to retrive device data with corresponding access token specifying in the request. Is there any options to get all devices data from device group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say multiple device attributes, are you asking for:

1. Get ALL attributes from ONE device? If so you can use:
   `curl -v -X GET "https://thingsboard.cloud/api/v1/$ACCESS_TOKEN/attributes`
2. Get ALL attributes for ALL devices in a specific device group. This is harder, you will need to use the full rest api found at https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html

If you need option 2, you will have to have a custom script to get a JWT token for your user credentials (or a low access level api user account) and use that to authenticate REST calls with the above link.

Pseudo process:

- Generate JWT token using user credentials.
- Use REST calls to `entity-group-controller > getEntityGroupsByType` with `groupType = 'DEVICE'`
- Loop through that for the group that you want
- Use the corresponding groupId in a `entity-group-controller > getEntities` call
- Loop through the returned entities and either execute Method 1 (above) on them or do a `telemetry-controller > getAttributes` call.

That's far more than 1 HTTP call though...

You could wrap it into a function so to make it easier to use, but I don't think you can reduce the number of calls further.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Actualy, I need to get device attributes for more than 1000 devices. I was thinking about getting all the attributes by calling a single device group API. But I guess I have to follow your path and have to call multiple http requests. It seems very much time consuming. Hope there's any alternative.

Comment: @PallabChowdhury There honestly may be a better way to do this, but this is currently the best method that I'm aware of (I also use it in my application). If you do find an alternative I'd love to hear of it. Cheers

Comment: Sure. Now, I am exporting all the devices data to a different server and retrieve data from there. I think it will be better to use TB as an intermediate broker and use separate server for production. Hope it helps.